# How to use loop for multiple value in array in Php with array boxes in front of name?

Tags: php, yii2

I am new in programming and learning PHP and Yii2 now . I need to use looping for multiple value in array . I am using array boxes in front of name here.

My input fields are :-

```
<div class="row thisIsCloned">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-xs-12">
        <label for="">Salary Head</label>
        <?php

        $dept = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\modules\hrm\models\HrmSalaryHead::find()->where(['status'=>1])->all(), 'id', 'salaryHead');
        echo Select2::widget([
            'name' => 'HrmRemuneration[0][salaryHead]',
            'data' => $dept,
            'options' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Salary Head ...',
                'id'=>'salaryHead',
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true,
            ],
        ]);

        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <label for="">Salary Amount in </label> ( <span class="rupee">Rs. </span> <span class="percentage" style="display:none">%</span> )
        <input type="checkbox" name="HrmRemuneration[0][checkbox]" value="1" class="status">
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="HrmRemuneration[0][checkbox]" >
        <span><input type="number" class="form-control" name="HrmRemuneration[0][salaryAmount]" required=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <button id="thisIsClonNewRowButton" type="button" class="pull-right quantity-right-plus btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 28px;height: 27px !important; padding: 3px 6px !important;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="renderremuneration"></div>
```

For my controllers where I POST to :-

```
public function actionRemuneration()
{
 $model=new HrmRemuneration();
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $a=($_POST["HrmRemuneration"]);



  $count = count($a);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $pmodel = new HrmRemuneration();
        $pmodel->salaryHead=$model[$i]['salaryHead'];
        $pmodel->amountCalc=$model[$i]['amountCalc'];

        if(!$pmodel->save())
        {
            $this->Message('Sorry !! Error occurs in adding Salary Head', 1); 
            return $this->redirect(['/hrm/settings/addsalaryhead']);
        }
    }
}

 }
 else
 {  
 return $this->render('remuneration',['model'=>$model]);
 }  
}
```

How can I post the value that uses the array box in front of name? Input Fields name like `HrmRemuneration[0]['salaryHead']` are used. How can I do that ?

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean with "array box" ?

Comment: [ ] <- array box

Comment: so you want the index? for example to get the 0 from this: `HrmRemuneration[0]['salaryHead']`

Comment: i want to grab the post value in my controller but cannot find a way for that . What am doing now is   $model=new HrmRemuneration();
   if (isset($_POST)) {
    $a=($_POST["HrmRemuneration"]);
    var_dump($a['salaryHead']);
    exit();
 
   }

Comment: and you aren't getting anything in your var_dump or what?

Comment: sooo i searched a little bit (sorry am not really familiar with Yii, but maybe this will help you? 

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/64351-how-to-get-post-value-in-a-controller/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$array[$i]['attr_name'];`  and not   `$array['attr_name'][$i];`

```
 $count = count($model);
 for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $pmodel = new HrmSalaryHead();
        $pmodel->salaryHead=$model[$i]['salaryHead'];
        $pmodel->amountCalc=$model[$i]['amountCalc'];

        if(!$pmodel->save())
        {
            $this->Message('Sorry !! Error occurs in adding Salary Head', 1); 
            return $this->redirect(['/hrm/settings/addsalaryhead']);
        }
```

Comment: i used a foreach loop .. how can i save this value using foreach loop here ? can u help me ? and in using for loop how can i count the attribute here before for loop ?

Comment: your code  is based  on for loop .. which code you are referring ?

Comment: ok !! in for loop also how can i count the value ? it shows error while counting the value

Comment: I don't uderstand your question  .. which value you want to count?  .. you have $i that count the number of iteration ..  so  .. explain better please

Comment: $count = count($model['salaryHead']); , i cannot count this value .. this count is used in for loop

Comment: for obtain the number of models  you should use count($model)    only

Comment: can you please write a code for this . i mean full code of for loop

Comment: counting $model gives the number of array not number of model .. I had updated my controllers again ..looks in question

Comment: the number of yuor models should be in  $_POST["HrmRemuneration"]  so count($a)  should give you the number of different isnatnce of  HrmRemuneration you have posted ..